# Щегол и щеголь - есть ли родство?

Tags: этимология

Щегол и щеголь - есть ли родство?

Я правда не знаю, в словари пока не залезал.

Answer (score 1):

Щегол - слово в русском языке известно, по крайней мере, с 17 века, о.-с. корень звукоподражательный (сравнить: сокол).

Щёголь - сначала появляется как прозвище, но оно, очевидно, связано с названием щегла,  "изумительное красивой, пестро разукрашенной" птицы.

Об этом можно судить по переводам на другие языки: 1762 год - щегол, 1771 год - франт.

Comment: А источник того, что "очевидно связано": Ну и с "переводами" ничего не понял.

Comment: Материал взят из словаря Черных.  А с переводами вот что: сначала прозвище "щеголь"  переводили как  название птицы - щегол,  то есть без определенного добавочного смысла, а потом уже то же самое прозвище стали переводить как франт (модник).

Comment: Ссылку тогда давайте на Черныха. И вообще на источник. А то воспринимается как ваша имха.  А насчет переводов... С какого языка на какой, простите начали переводить? С русского на русский?

Comment: В 1762 году перевод на фр.язык, в 1771 годе - на нем. язык. Нет сомнений, что   эта информация поможет вам  окончательно разобраться с щеглами и щёголями. Да и ситуация в общем-то несложная. Сначала  молодого человека называют щеглом за красивый (пестрый) наряд-прикид, потом слово приобретает новое, переносное  значение.  Именно этот момент и зафиксирован разными переводами.

Comment: Вообще-то я не собирался окончательно разбираться. Тем более - исходя из столь сомнительной информации. Откуда информация о переводе на "фр." язык - как это мне может помочь?

Comment: По сути. Вы заставили меня все-таки посмотреть в Фасмера. Он далеко не столь однозначен. щеголь у него - неясного происхождения, а щегол совсем не звукоподражательное.

Comment: Не стоит понимать мое сообщение буквально, это я так пыталась выразить иронию. Ваш комментарий показался мне невежливым. Вы употребляете много  насмешливых  выражений и совсем не пользуетесь словами   учтивыми (политес не соблюдаете). Вот , к примеру, пишете, что  ваш же  вопрос вам не очень интересен, да и форум считаете источником сомнительной информации. Итак, продолжаем разбираться с щёголями и щеглами.

Comment: Вы по сути. Церемониальную часть опустим. Про политес - отдельной статьёй пожалуйста. Конкретно. Где я такое написал, по какому поводу. Обычно такие обвинения оказываются либо блефом, либо недоразумением, неправильным пониманием порожденным.

Comment: Про источник сомнительной информации. Я не помню, чтобы такое писал, но вообще-то да, информация с форумов всегда сомнительна, если речь идет о фактах, а не личных данных и/или мнениях. Обычно такая информация подлежит проверке в словарях или справочниках. Ради чего и дается ссылка.

Comment: Шанский согласен с Черных, перенос названия с птицы на человека - дело обычное, например: "Нам уже понятно, что вы за гусь! (М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита).